# Why does my VS Code terminal keep getting terminated?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm facing a problem in running my programs on Visual Studio Code.
Every time I open the terminal it exits terminates with exit code `4294967295`. Please help me resolve this issue.

```
The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\wsl.exe" terminated with exit code: 4294967295.
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the wsl.exe command inside the running WSL distribution? First close the running wsl.exe window and run the command from another command prompt window. If that didn't work try with another distribution.